# Python/Django How do I make it so that only the creator of an object/post can see a delete/edit function button for their post?

Tags: python, django

I am currently new to python developing and am currently in school to learn multiple stacks. My code is in the most basic form. I haven't gotten to authenticated yet nor have i ever been introduced to KWARGS  or pk. I also don't even know what those are at this moment. How would I make it so that the delete button only shows up to the side of the "Thought" post of the User who created the object so that they can delete it themselves but the button wouldn't be available for other User's posts? Also, how would I implement a single Like/Dislike button that transitions back and forth for every Object post in the most simple form of what I have learned thus far? this is my current code.

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
import re
import bcrypt

class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def registration_validator(self, postData):
        errors = {}
        EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')
        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(postData['email']):    # test whether a field matches the pattern            
            errors['email'] = ("Invalid email address!")
        if len(self.filter(email = postData['email'])) > 0:
            errors['email'] = "Email address has already been taken!"
        if len(postData['first_name']) < 2:
            errors["first_name"] = "Insufficient amount of character letters, you must type over 2 characters for your first name!"
        if len(postData['last_name']) < 2:
            errors["last_name"] = "Insufficient amount of character letters, you must type over 2 characters for your last name!"
        if len(postData['password']) < 8:
            errors["password"] = "Insufficient amount of character letters, you must type over 8 characters for your password!"
        if postData['password'] != postData['confpw']:
            errors["confpw"] = "Passwords do not match!"
        if (len(postData['first_name']) < 1) or (len(postData['last_name']) < 1) or (len(postData['password']) < 1) or (len(postData['confpw']) < 1) or (len(postData['email']) < 1):
            errors["empty_fields"] = "All fields require input to register!"
        return errors

class ThoughtManager(models.Manager):
    def thought_validator(self, postData):
        errors = {}
        if len(postData['desc']) < 5:
            errors['desc'] = "Insufficient amount of character letters, you must type over 5 characters for your description!"
        if len(postData['desc']) < 1:
            errors['desc'] = "Please provide a thought!" 
        return errors    

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager()

class Thought(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="thoughts")
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes", blank=True)
    objects = ThoughtManager()

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages
import bcrypt

# within index
def index(request):
    return render(request, "thought_board/index.html")

def register(request):
    errors = User.objects.registration_validator(request.POST)
    if len(errors) > 0:
        for key, value in errors.items():
            messages.error(request, value, extra_tags = key)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        password = request.POST['password']
        pw_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())
        user = User.objects.create(first_name=request.POST['first_name'], last_name=request.POST['last_name'], email=request.POST['email'], password=pw_hash)
        request.session['user_id'] = user.id
        return redirect('/thoughts')

def login(request):
        user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'])
        if not user:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid email!")
            return redirect('/')
        logged_user = user[0]
        if bcrypt.checkpw(request.POST['password'].encode(), logged_user.password.encode()):
            request.session['user_id'] = logged_user.id
            return redirect('/thoughts')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid email and/or password!")
            return redirect('/')

def logout(request):
    request.session.clear()
    return redirect('/')

#within thoughts
def thoughts(request):
    context = {
        "user": User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']),
        "thoughts": Thought.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "thought_board/thoughts.html", context)

def add(request):
    errors = Thought.objects.thought_validator(request.POST)
    if len(errors) > 0:
        for key, value in errors.items():
            messages.error(request, value, extra_tags = key)
        return redirect('/thoughts')
    else:
        Thought.objects.create(desc=request.POST['desc'], user=User.objects.get(id=request.session["user_id"]))
        return redirect('/thoughts')

def delete(request, id):
    thought = Thought.objects.get(id=id)
    thought.delete()
    return redirect('/thoughts')

#within views
def views(request, id):
    thought = Thought.objects.get(id=id)
    likes = thought.like.all()
    is_liked = likes.filter(id=id)
    is_liked = False
    if thought.like.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
    context = {
        "thought": thought,
        "users": likes,
        "is_liked": is_liked,
        "logged_user": User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    }
    return render(request, "thought_board/details.html", context)

def like(request, id):
    thought = Thought.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    thought.like.add(user)
    return redirect('/thoughts/'+id)

def unlike(request, id):
    thought = Thought.objects.get(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    thought.like.remove(user)
    return redirect('thoughts/'+id)
```

This is the template where my delete button will be placed

**thoughts.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Thought Board</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.container{
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.nav{
    float: right;
}
.button{
    font-size: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header-desc{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
#desc-thoughts{
    width: 60%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 32px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}
#add-thoughts{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #2b78e4;
    border: solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#text-area{
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    resize: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 465px;
}
.inline-input{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
.inline{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
.p{
    width: 100px;
}
#thought-board{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.details a{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    margin-left: 102px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.delete{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
.delete-btn{
    background-color: #cc0101;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
}
#likes{
    margin-left: 455px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
#line{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 750px;
}
</style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="/" class="button">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <h1>Hello {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}!</h1>
        <div>
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">    
            {% for message in messages %}    
                <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>    
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
            <form action="/thoughts/add/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="header-desc">
                    <input type="text" id="desc-thoughts" name="desc" placeholder="Post a Great Thought Here!">
                    <button type="submit"  id="add-thoughts">Add Thought!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr id="line" align="left">
        {% for thought in thoughts %}
        <div id="thought-board">
            <div class="inline-input p">
                <p id="p">{{thought.user.first_name}} says:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="inline">
                <textarea readonly id="text-area">{{thought.desc}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="delete">
                <form action="/thoughts/{{thought.id}}/delete/">
                    <button type="submit" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <a href="/thoughts/{{thought.id}}/" method="GET">Details</a>
                <p id="likes">{{thought.like.count}} people like this</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where the one button toggle like/dislike(or unlike) will be

**details.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Thought Board</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.container{
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.table-secondary{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.table th{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.table td{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.nav{
    float: right;
}
.dashboard{
    font-size: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.logout{
    font-size: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#text-area{
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    resize: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 555px;
    background-color: white;
}
.inline-input{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
.label{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.input{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.btn{
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #009e0f;
    border: solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
    color:white;
    margin-left: 590px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.btn2{
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    border: solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px black;
    color:black;
    margin-left: 590px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.table{
    width: 59%;
}
</style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header float-right">
        <form action="/thoughts/" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="/thoughts/" class="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="/" class="logout">Logout</a>
        </form>
        </div>
            <div class="input">
                <div class="inline-input label">
                    <label>{{thought.user.first_name}} says:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-input">
                    <textarea id="text-area" readonly>{{thought.desc}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="/thoughts/{{thought.id}}/like/" method="POST">
                {% if is_liked == logged_user %}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" value="{{thought.id}}" class="btn">Like</button>
            </form>
                {% else %}
            <form action="/thoughts/{{thought.id}}/unlike/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" value="{{thought.id}}" class="btn2">Unlike</button>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        <div class="people-likes">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <p>People who liked this thought:<p>
                <thead class="table-secondary">
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                </thead>
                {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to coding/programming. I could also have unnecessary code added to my views/model page. Please point on any errors and/or suggestions to improve my beginner level coding/programming.

**EDIT:**Sorry for the inconvenience! I forgot to add my templates.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your views.py to be like this

```
def remove(request, id):
   item = Thought.objects.get(pk=id)
   if request.user == item.user:
      Thought.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
      return redirect('/')

def edit(request, id):
  item = Thought.objects.get(pk=id)
  if request.user == item.user:
      ...
      //write your code here
```

hope this help you ^_^

Comment: thanks for an answer. unfortunately it broke my page. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong exactly.

Comment: could you please show me screenshot of the error you got

Comment: ```ValueError at /thoughts/21/delete/
The view apps.thought_board.views.delete didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.```

Sorry i'm quite new. I didn't know how to message you or send a screenshot of the error page i received.

Comment: yes you need to add a page to redirect to in the remove() function i updated the remove function try it ^_^